# Transfer the output of a chrome extension to a server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, remote-server, content-script

I have a chrome extension which outputs my bookmarks into the console. But instead of outputting I want to send all of these bookmarks to my remote server using content scripts.

How can I do this ? Are there any special permissions to be included in the manifest.json file ?

```
function getBookmarks()
{
     ........ (*get the bookmarks and store them in an array BookArray)
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "server_domain", true);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        (*send the entire array to the server *)
 }
}
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XMLHttpRequest to post data to your server.

The only manifest's field you need to add is **permissions**, to enable *cross-origin XMLHttpRequest*.

Note that as of Chrome 13, content scripts are able to do cross-origin requests.

The stable Chrome version today is 17, but, if you need to be backwards compatible before version 13, you'll need to implement you XMLHttpRequest in your background.html and do a bit of extra code to make it work.

Comment: I have added my code above along with the XMLHttpRequest i'm using. 

I need to send the entire array to the server. I am not sure how to do that.